# Use `trans_choice()` in request validation messages with validation rule parameter

Tags: laravel, request, translation, validationrules

I need a request validation rule to return a custom message upon failure, and since the field being validating is an array with a `min:x` rule i'd like to have a custom message for both singular and plural variations.

I'm just wondering how to pass to the `trans_choice()` function the `:min` parameter from the validation rule:

#### Translation file:

```
'array' => [
    'field' => [
        'min' => 'You need to select at least one item.|you need to select at least :min items',
    ],
],
```

#### Request `message()` method:

```
public function messages() {
    'my.array.field.min' => trans_choice('translations::array.field.min', ???),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's nothing built into Laravel to use `trans_choice` whenever you can pluralise a translation string.

A way you could solve that is by temporarily (or permanently, whatever fits your use-case) changing [the replacer](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#using-extensions) for [the `min` rule](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ReplacesAttributes.php#L88) to something like this:

```
Validator::replacer('min', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters, $validator) {  
    $minValue = $parameters[0];

    $message = Str::contains($message, '|')
        ? trans_choice($message, $minValue)
        : $message;
  
    return str_replace(':min', $minValue, $message);
});
```

Or by extending the Validator factory to work in your favour, but since that requires you to change many of it's methods I don't really recommend that.